# Hyphen missing in my Custom Post Type URL Slug

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a new Custom Post Type(Earnings Transcripts) in WordPress using the below code. The name of my Custom Post Type is **"Earnings Transcripts"** which is 2 words. So the slug should be **"earnings-transcripts"**. Instead the URL is **"earningstranscripts"**. What am I missing here?

```
function custom_post_type() {
   
    // Earnings Transcripts 
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Earnings Transcripts', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Earnings Transcripts', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentysixteen' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Earnings Transcripts', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'Earnings Transcripts' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );     
    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'Earnings Transcripts', $args );    
    
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late. I hope this one will be helpful for others who face this scenario.

When it comes to Custom Post types, Slugs should always have underscores instead of hyphens as there are various places in WordPress core that utilize the slugs, and that would break if not using an underscore.

You can check this article for more details on this topic: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/why-is-underscore-permitted-in-the-post-type-but-dash-is-disallowed/#post-505820

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the

```
// Registering your Custom Post Type
register_post_type( 'Earnings Transcripts', $args );
```

A change like this:

```
register_post_type('earnings-transcripts', $args);
```

The below function will remove the slug from the permalink

```
 function rf_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {
  if ( 'earnings-transcripts' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
    return $post_link;
  }
  $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
  return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'rf_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
```

The below function will fix the issue of showing the 404 Not found error on the detailed post pages under this custom post type

```
 function rf_parse_request( $query ) {
  if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
    return;
  }
  if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'earnings-transcripts', 'page' ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rf_parse_request' );
```

Comment: Thanks your code is working fine in bits & pieces. On the Landing page of custom post type its working fine but I would like to remove the "earnings-transcripts" slug while viewing the detailed post under that custom post type.

Comment: Check this WP plugin and Code:
https://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/

Comment: Slug is removed but it is displaying Not Found Page on Detailed Post.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly add the above 2 functions in functions.php file which i mentioned in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
"rewrite" => array( "slug" => "earnings-transcripts", "with_front" => true ),
```

Add this parameter in `$args`, it will work.

Comment: Thanks your code is working fine in bits & pieces. On the Landing page of custom post type its working fine but I would like to remove the "earnings-transcripts" slug while viewing the detailed post under that custom post type.

Comment: Look into this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210/110795

Comment: I tried the answers but it is not working. Can you be specific on which answer I should look for?

Comment: You just need to click on the link, it will automatically scroll and take you to answer, which I am talking about.